# Cartesian product of two collections of sets?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

If we have
$\mathcal{G} = \{\phi, \{0\}, \{1\}, \{1,2\} \},$
would $\mathcal{G} \times \mathcal{G}$ have the form $\{\phi, (\{0\}, \{0\}), (\{0\}, \{1\}), (\{0\}, \{0, 1\}), \dots \}$?

In that case, what would an example of $(w_1, w_2) \in B \in \mathcal{G} \times \mathcal{G}$ be?

**My working:**
Take for example $B = (\{0\}, \{0, 1\})$. This is not a set; so, I don't understand how one could take an element $(w_1, w_2) \in B$.

P.S.: I am taking a Probability Theory class now and even though I did a Measure Theory class last term, I am finding things very difficult. But I really want to get good at this stuff. Would there be any reading material you'd recommend? (I find the lectures hard to follow.)

EDIT:
I encountered this statement in the book Theory of Probability and Random Processes by Koralov. In Definition 2.1, he states:

> A finite-dimenstional cylinder is a set of the form $$A = \{\omega: (\omega_{t_1}, \dots, \omega_{t_k}) \in B \},$$ where $t_1, \dots, t_k
> \geq 1$, and $B \in \mathcal{G} \times \dots \times \mathcal{G}$ (k
> times).

Comment: "Take for example B=({0},{0,1}). This is not a set; so, I don't understand how one could take an element (w1,w2)∈B." You are correct.  "$(w_1, w_2) \in B \in \mathcal{G} \times \mathcal{G}$" doesn't actually make any sense.  Pretty much for the reason you gave.  If $B\in \mathcal G \times \mathcal G$ then $B$ is an ordered par of sets and $B$ itself would not have an ordered pair as an element... (Although an ordered pair is a sort of set.. a set where order matters and a set with exactly two elements. It's elements would be.. the first item in the pair and.. the second item in the pair.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The context of the definition that you give in your edit is quite important. The 'Cartesian Product' can then be interpreted in a different way.

First let's denote $G$ as the set of the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{G}$, i.e. $\mathcal{G} = (G,\mathcal{G})$. Further set  $\mathcal{F} := \mathcal{G} \times \dots \times \mathcal{G}$. If you think of $\mathcal{F}$ as being a $\sigma$-Algebra on the power set of the Cartesian Product of $G$ instead of the Cartesian Product itself, then the expression

$$(\omega_{t_1}, \dots, \omega_{t_k}) \in B \in \mathcal{F} \ \big(=\mathcal{G} \times \dots \times \mathcal{G}\big)$$
makes much more sense.

Because then $\mathcal{F}$ is a subset of $\mathcal{P}(G^{k})$ (where $G$ is the set of the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{G}$) and hence every member $B$ of it is a subset of the Cartesian Product $G \times \dots \times G$.

In fact, in the context of your definition in the book this "$\mathcal{G} \times \dots \times \mathcal{G}$" is - by abuse of notation - a shorthand for the Product $\sigma$-algebra of $k$-times the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{G}$.

Sometimes this is denoted $\mathcal{G} \otimes \dots \otimes \mathcal{G}$ to prevent confusion with the Cartesian Product.

(And the book then goes on to make a connection between the $k$-times Product $\sigma$-algebra and the $n$-times Product $\sigma$-algebra for $k \leq n$. As seen [here](https://books.google.ch/books?id=tlWOphOFRgwC&printsec=frontcover&hl=de#v=onepage&q&f=false) on page 25.)

---

About your P.S.: I usually recommend Klenke's [*Probability Theory*](http://books.google.ch/books?id=tcm3y5UJxDsC&printsec=frontcover&hl=de#v=onepage&q&f=false) which starts with some detailed measure theory then covers the basic theory, stochastic processes, martingales up to stochastic differential calculus. (Plus I got the notation of the Product $\sigma$-algebra from there.)

But you should have a look at many books to find one that might suit you and your class best.

Comment: Isn't it $\{\Pi_{i=1}^k X_i|X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_k\in\mathcal G\}$ rather than $\mathscr P(\mathcal G^k)$? If $\mathcal G=\{\phi,\{1\}\}$ and $k=2$, then the former would give $\{\phi,\{(1,1)\}\}$ while the latter would give $\mathscr P(\{(\phi,\phi),(\phi,\{1\}),(\{1\},\phi),(\{1\},\{1\})\})$, which has 16 elements.

Comment: @W.Zhu your first collection of sets will create $\mathcal{G} \otimes ... \otimes \mathcal{G}$ (cylinder sets).

Note that in this notation $\mathcal{G} \otimes ... \otimes \mathcal{G} \neq \mathcal{G}^{k}$

Comment: But you are right, it should be "a subset of $\mathcal{P}(G^{k})$ where $G$ is the set of the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{G}$", i.e. $\mathcal{G} \subset \mathcal{P}(G)$

I'll adapt my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Almost.

$\emptyset$ wouldn't be in the cartesian product but $(\emptyset,\emptyset)$ will be.

Don't overthink it.  $A\times B$ is nothing more than the set of ordered pairs and an ordered pair is just a pair of an element from the first set and an element for the second.... in order.

So if $\color{blue}{\mathcal{G} = \{\phi, \{0\}, \{1\}, \{1,2\} \}}$ is a set with four elements and $\color{red}{\mathcal{G} = \{\phi, \{0\}, \{1\}, \{1,2\} \}}$ is the same set of four elementts then  $\color{blue}{\mathcal{G}}\times \color{red}{\mathcal{G}}$ will be a set of the sixteen pairs that can be made:

$\color{blue}{\mathcal{G}}\times \color{red}{\mathcal{G}}= \{(\color{blue}{\emptyset},\color{red}{\emptyset}),(\color{blue}{\emptyset},\color{red}{\{0\}}),(\color{blue}{\emptyset},\color{red}{\{1\}}),(\color{blue}{\emptyset},\color{red}{\{1,2\}}),$

$\{(\color{blue}{\{0\}}$$,\color{red}{\emptyset}),(\color{blue}{\{0\}},\color{red}{\{0\}}),(\color{blue}{\{0\}},\color{red}{\{1\}}),(\color{blue}{\{0\}},\color{red}{\{1,2\}}),$

$\{(\color{blue}{\{1\}}$$,\color{red}{\emptyset}),(\color{blue}{\{1\}},\color{red}{\{0\}}),(\color{blue}{\{1\}},\color{red}{\{1\}}),(\color{blue}{\{1\}},\color{red}{\{1,2\}}),$

$\{(\color{blue}{\{1,2\}}$$,\color{red}{\emptyset}),(\color{blue}{\{1,2\}},\color{red}{\{0\}}),(\color{blue}{\{1,2\}},\color{red}{\{1\}}),(\color{blue}{\{1,2\}},\color{red}{\{1,2\}})\}$

Don't overthink it.

......

> In that case, what would an example of (w1,w2)∈B∈G×G be?

Oh.....

*Now* I see why you were overthinking it.   That statement makes no sense.

$B\in \mathcal G \times \mathcal G$ would mean that $B$ is an ordered pair $(J,K)$ where $J$ is one of the four sets and $K$ is one of the four sets: $\emptyset, \{0\}, \{1\}, \{1,2\}$.

Then, if I were to say $w \in B = (J,K)$ then that means $w$ is one of either $J$ or $K$.

So that makes no sense. Are you sure the statement wasn't:

> $(w_1, w_2) = B \in  \mathcal G \times \mathcal G$

or maybe

> $(w_1, w_2) \in B \subset  \mathcal G \times \mathcal G$

?

Comment: Thanks for confirming correctness of the cartesian product. I will add a bit more detail in the question; please check that.

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\set}[1]{\left\{ #1 \right\}}
\newcommand{\G}{\mathcal{G}}
$It might be easier to process if you name every set with a letter, say...

$$A = \varnothing \quad B = \set{0} \quad C = \set{1} \quad D = \set{1,2}$$

Then $\G = \set{A,B,C,D}$ and $\G^2$ is given by

\begin{align*}
\G \times \G = \Big\{
&(A,A),(A,B),(A,C),(A,D),\\
&(B,A),(B,B),(B,C),(B,D),\\
&(C,A),(C,B),(C,C),(C,D),\\
&(D,A),(D,B),(D,C),(D,D)\Big\}
\end{align*}

You can then replace $A,B,C,D$ with their explicit definitions:

\begin{align*}
\G \times \G = \Big\{
&\Big(\varnothing,\varnothing\Big) \; , \;\Big(\varnothing,\set{0}\Big) \; , \;\Big(\varnothing,\set{1}\Big) \; , \;\Big(\varnothing,\set{1,2}\Big),\\
&\Big(\set{0},\varnothing\Big) \; , \;\Big(\set{0},\set{0}\Big) \; , \;\Big(\set{0},\set{1}\Big) \; , \;\Big(\set{0},\set{1,2}\Big),\\
&\Big(\set{1},\varnothing\Big) \; , \;\Big(\set{1},\set{0}\Big) \; , \;\Big(\set{1},\set{1}\Big) \; , \;\Big(\set{1},\set{1,2}\Big),\\
&\Big(\set{1,2},\varnothing\Big) \; , \;\Big(\set{1,2},\set{0}\Big) \; , \;\Big(\set{1,2},\set{1}\Big) \; , \;\Big(\set{1,2},\set{1,2}\Big)\Big\}
\end{align*}

More loosely,

$$\G \times \G = \Big\{ \text{all possible pairs } (X,Y) \text{ where } X,Y \in \G \Big\}$$

What you end up with, then, is ordered pairs of sets. Be careful with the ordered pair $(\varnothing,\varnothing)$; you seem to think that might be equal to $\varnothing$, but recall that ordered pairs have a formal definition:

$$(x,y) = \Big\{ \set{x},\set{x,y} \Big\}$$

You should see why, then, $(\varnothing,\varnothing) \ne \varnothing$.

Of course, $\G^2$ is still a set, so you can take elements from it, and those elements are ordered pairs. If we say $(w_1,w_2) \in \G \times \G$, then we are just saying $(w_1,w_2)$ is some ordered pair in $\G \times \G$ (and, moreover, that means $w_1 \in \G$ and $w_2 \in \G$ from definitions).

But can we take elements of a $B \in \G \times \G$ instead? Like you saw: can we take $(w_1,w_2) \in B$ for $B \in \G \times \G$? *(To avoid confusion, this need not be the same $B$ as earlier.)*

Note that $B \in \G \times \G$ may be characterized as set in terms of ordered pairs. It might be best to work with an example, say $B = (\set{1,2},\set{1,2})$. Then

$$B = \Big( \set{1,2},\set{1,2} \Big)
= \Big\{ \set{1,2} \; ,  \; \big\{ \set{1,2},\set{1,2} \big\} \Big\}$$

but

$$(w_1,w_2) = \Big\{ w_1, \set{w_1,w_2} \Big\}$$

If $(w_1,w_2) \in B$, then it means that $(w_1,w_2)$ is represented by the set, larger set in $B$.

Answer (score 1):

$(a,b)$ is a way to denote an element of the Cartesian product $A \times B$ where $a \in A$ and $b \in B$.

There are [several ways](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_pair?wprov=sfti1) is set theory to define the ordered pair. A usual one is

$$(a,b)= \{\{a\}, \{a,b \}\}.$$

Based on that you can derive $\mathcal G \times \mathcal G$.

Comment: OP's Cartesian product is not correct, since he has $\varnothing \in \mathcal{G}^2$ which is not an ordered pair.

Comment: @EeveeTrainer You’re right. I read it too quickly.